# Calculate the max level of inheritance using an AST in Python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a Python AST to analyze source code attributes in a given Python Project.

In particular, I need to calculate the max level of inheritance for all Python classes.

Example: If I have three classes, A, B, and C, and A inherits from B, and B inherits from C, the max level of inheritance is:

A: 2 (because it directly inherits from B, and indirectly from C)

B: 1 (because it only inherits from C)

C: 0 (because it not inherits)

I write the following code, but unfortunately, the final output is incorrect (the output is A: 1, B: 1, and C: 0)

```py
def calculate_inheritance(class_def_node):
    try:
        bases = class_def_node.bases
        if not bases:
            return 0
        return max(calculate_inheritance(base) for base in bases) + 1
    except AttributeError:
        return 0


def createAST(project_path):
    project_name = os.path.basename(project_path)
    data = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(project_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".py"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                    try:
                        tree = ast.parse(f.read())
                    except:
                        continue
                    for node in tree.body:
                        if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
                            class_name = node.name
                            inheritance_level = calculate_inheritance(node)
                            data.append((project_name, file_path, class_name, inheritance_level))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Project", "File Path", "Class Name", "Inheritance Level"])
    return df
```

I think that the wrong part is that the code does not consider indirect inheritance, however, I have no idea how I can fix it(in addition, I am also not sure that the code could extract the level of inheritance for multiple inheritances).

Answer (score 0):

You can first walk the `ast` of your source code and build a directed graph of the class names as nodes and their descendents as edges. Then, this graph can be traversed to find the depths.

Example source code

```py
class C:
   pass

class B(C):
   pass

class A(B):
   pass
```

```py
import ast

with open('src.py') as f:
   a = ast.parse(f.read())

graph = {i.name:[ast.unparse(j) for j in i.bases] for i in ast.walk(a) \
           if isinstance(i, ast.ClassDef)}

queue, results = [(a, 0) for a, b in graph.items() if not b], {}
while queue:
   node, c = queue.pop(0)
   results[node] = c
   for a, b in graph.items():
      if node in b:
         queue.append((a, c + 1))

print(results)
```

Output:

```
{'C': 0, 'B': 1, 'A': 2}
```